# Configuring Oracle 10g Express

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, http, oracle

I was wondering how to configure oralce 10g http service (http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex) to listen on some other interfaces (like http://192.168.50.128:8080/apex)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [enable remote access](http://www.randomsupport.com/rs/blogs/index.php?title=oracle-10g-express-web-interface-remote-&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1).

In SQL*Plus (SQL Command line) run

EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);